# How do I backup/restore database encryption key in order to restore on new server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore, encryption

I am currently in the process of restoring a TDE encrypted database to another instance. I have backed up master key and certificate, and have restored them to the new server fine, but I am still incurring the following message -

```
Msg 33111, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Cannot find server certificate with thumbprint '0x85187A0021B33712B314113A5F75DBE2EFD118F2'.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

TDE was set up on the source with a database encryption key ....

```
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TDE_CERT
GO
```

and can be found under `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys`

and the thumbprint is of this. I have not restored this to the new server. How do I go about this?

Not understanding how I restore/create this on the new server, or am I going the wrong way about it? Relatively new to dba-ing, so please be gentle.

Comment: Did you run the following, changed for your data, of course?   CREATE CERTIFICATE YourCert
FROM FILE = 'D:\Path\Subpath\YourCert.cert'
WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE = 'D:\Path\SubPath\YourCert.privatekey', 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourCertPassword-xyzzy');

Comment: Yes, I did. This is why i thought this should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the thumbprint error the certificate was not created properly from the Source Server's Cert/Key backups.

I found this question which was already answered with a solution for you:

[Restore encrypted database to another server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/restore-encrypted-database-to-another-server?rq=1)