# Set "Encryption Enabled" to FALSE...what can go wrong?

Tags: sql-server, migration, log-shipping, transparent-data-encryption

I'm migrating a database from `SQL Server 2012` to `SQL Server 2014` on the same server.

I'm configuring LOG SHIPPING on a database that is apparently encrypted:

[image]

When setting the log shipping I got this message (when it started to restore the database from a backup):

[image]

I'm the new DBA here and there's no report of master keys, encrypted keys etc.

I'm setting log shipping from SQL2012 to SQL2014 (with norecovery). What could go wrong if I set this database to `Encryption enabled - false` and try to restore the database with the log shipping wizard?

There are some questions about this problem , like [This one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/restore-encrypted-database-to-another-server?rq=1), but all of them say I need the password.

I Just found this certificate on `master > security > certificates` on the primary server (2012):

[image]

And there are some code samples over the Interet but I really can't trust them (I don't think it's too simple):

```
`USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET ENCRYPTION OFF
GO
USE DatabaseName
GO
DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
GO`
```

---

Edit1:

[In this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76443/how-do-i-backup-restore-database-encryption-key-in-order-to-restore-on-new-serve?lq=1) Dylon says:

> If you are receiving the thumbprint error the certificate was not created properly from the Source Server's Cert/Key backups.

I'm confused about this topic and all I want is to disable encryption, restore the database on the other server to log shipping, and some day, activate encryption.

---

Edit2:

On `Database > tasks > manage database encryption` there are some options too:

[image]

Disabling this, I would be able to backup the database again, and restore it on the new instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not disable TDE. Besides being a lengthy size-of-data operation, it was established initially for a reason and you may be breaking whatever compliance/operations reason exists for TDE.

Rather set up log shipping properly in the presence of TDE. Follow the steps described in [Move a TDE Protected Database to Another SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff773063.aspx). You are going to *export* the TDE certificate from the original server and then *import* it on the standby server, making sure it is encrypted with the `master` database master key and the database `master` master key is in turn encrypted with the service master key. After that, if done correctly, restore operations should succeed as the required TDE certificate is present.

To copy the certificate: The certificate is in the `master` database of the primary instance. You need to run:

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE TDE_CERT 
 TO FILE <where to save cert> 
 WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = <where to save private key>, 
  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <password for the private key file>);
```

Then copy both cert and private key files to the secondary and restore it in `master` using:

```
 CREATE CERTIFICATE TDE_CERT 
  FROM FILE = <your copied cert file> 
  WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = <your copied private key file>,
   DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <password that protects private key file>);
```

`TDE_CERT` in `master` on the secondary needs to be encrypted with `master` database master key, which will likely need to be created.

Comment: @Resmus, thank you very much for your answer. I was talking with the manager, and we really don't need this encryption. It was made a long time ago by a DBA and we really don't need it now. But I will read your blog and see what I can do. Thank you very much and I will post the results later. And yes, our database is 1.5tb. it would take some time do disable encryption, right?

Comment: 1.5tb to disable TDE yes, will take a while. On the other hand, if you choose toe keep TDE, establish log shipping and *then* disable TDE there will be a *lot* of traffic downstream on the log_shipping pipe. Choose your poison.

Comment: Huum...Does the database will be blocked? as we need this as fast as possible, I really would like to try to disable TDE, restore the backup on the other instance and create the log shipping. the log shipping will be here for 2 days, and after that, we will kil the old instance. So, with `alter database MyDb SET ENCRYPTION OFF ...DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY` can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Disabling TDE is an online operation. The `SET ENCRYPTION OFF` only *starts* the decryption, you'll have to wait for the operation to finish. Poll `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` until `encryption_state` is 1 (unencrypted). Monitor your log usage, this operation may fill the log if log backup is no frequent enough.

Comment: @Resmus, I used `ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] SET ENCRYPTION OFF`. The column `percent_complete` is the percent of decryption rate, right? After that, should I use `DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY`? Again, thank you very much, I will study a lot about this topic.

Comment: Correct, the percentage shows the progress. You can run `DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY` after the decryption completes.

Comment: Also you'll need to make sure no log record overlaps any encrypted era of the database before attempting to restore on secondary. Start with a new full backup taken after the `DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY`.

Comment: Hey @Resanu. it worked. It took more than 10hrs. after drop the encryption  key I could restore the database ( is restoring now ) to the new instance. Also, the backup was really faster. with encryption it took like 5 hrs. Whitout it, took me less than 2hrs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the follow up. Now we can point here other who ask "how long will a 1.4Tb TDE removal last?" ;)

Comment: Also, now you can enable backup compression https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx : *Encrypted data compresses significantly less than equivalent unencrypted data. If TDE is used to encrypt a database, backup compression will not be able to significantly compress the backup storage. Therefore, using TDE and backup compression together is not recommended.*.